# Unable to get Product2.ExternalId from OpportunityLineItem SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

Below is the SOQL query that gets executed successfully in Workbench but unable to save the same query in apex code getting below error.

```
SELECT Quantity, Product2.ExternalId 
FROM OpportunityLineItem 
Where OpportunityId =: OppId
```

**Apex code snippet**

unable to save this in apex as it gives below error

```
opportunityLineItemList = [SELECT Quantity, Product2.ExternalId 
                           FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                           Where OpportunityId =: OppId];
```

> Error No Such column 'ExternalId' on entity Product2

FLS is been given to the field

Comment: Its working for me..Probably missing the permission.

Comment: Is your class is having API version 30.0  or higher ?
The ID of the related Product2 record. This is a read-only field available in API version 30.0 and later.

Comment: @bharath Permission is there otherwise it wouldn't have executed in workbench as well.

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande the api version is 36.0

Comment: @RCS Check for V 39.0 it should work

Comment: Try upgrading your class further to latest version

Comment: Yes it did work after the class was upgraded to version 40.0

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande - please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your class is having API version 30.0 or higher ? The ID of the related Product2 record. This is a read-only field available in API version 30.0 and later. 
Ref: [OpportunityLineItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm)